# how to edit apache2.conf file without disturbing puppetlabs/apache module default settings?

Tags: apache2, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I have installed the `puppetlabs-apache` module.  I am able to manage the vhosts but now I want to change/add contents of the default `apache2.conf` file of my client server.  Specifically, I have to add the lines

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/security
```

to the `apache2.conf` file.
How can I do the changes without disturbing the puppetlabs/apache module settings?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's configuration system, as set up by puppetlabs-apache, is designed so that you generally *don't* need to modify the main config file.  Instead, you normally want to drop files into the server's `conf.d/` directory, where it can find and load them automatically.  The module's [`apache::custom_config`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#defined-type-apachecustom_config) defined type serves this very purpose.

If for some reason you insist on deploying a modified version of the main config file, then you would do so by specifying the name of the appropriate ERB template as the value of class `apache`'s [`conf_template`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#conf_template) parameter.  If you intend to pursue this option then I strongly advise you to start with a copy of the default template that ships with the module, and make the needed modifications to that.  It is possible to break other functionalities of the module if you specify a template that fails to support them.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `templates/httpd.conf.erb` directly with your custom content.

If you reference this Apache module for multiple applications and your custom content is risky, you may want to duplicate the entire module and keep the customization to the template localized for that.

I was able to use this to enable Apache http2 via puppet in on my server by backing up the `templates/httpd.conf.erb` file and inserting the following line in the document.

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

Based on John's suggestion, it was also trivial to duplicate the `.erb` file before editing.

The only other step where I had to modify files in the module for http2 is to create my own `manifests/mod/http2.pp` file which I did just by duplicating the headers.pp file in the same directory and updating it with http2 instead of headers.

It seems like enabling http2 via Apache would be something really desired now, but this ticket has been open for about a year:

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-6537

I bring all of this up because this is very specific example where going into the module and extending it seems worthwhile - the module is so configurable out of the box it normally seems safest stay within its supported features.

Thanks for the answer, John.  It helped me resolve my feature request very quickly. I have no reputation so I can not respond to your answer directly.